# GIT : How to get latest changes from master branch to the custom branch using git commands?

Tags: windows, git, bitbucket, git-bash

Branch "**abcd/child**" is created from "**abcd/master**" . Changes are made to "**abcd/child**" and meanwhile "**abcd/master**" also have added changes. Now how to make sure the latest changes are pulled from "**abcd/master**" is available in "**abcd/child**" using **git commands** in git bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `abcd` is the name of your remote, here's how I'd do it:

```
git checkout child
git pull
git merge abcd/master
git push
```

When you checkout child, it'll probably say "set up to track remote abcd" or similar.

The `git pull` command does two things:  It fetches all updates from the server (on all branches) to your  local git repo, and it updates your branch to match what's on the remote.

The `git merge abcd\master` means to specifically bring in all of the commits that are on the remote's copy of the master branch. That's important because you may not have updated your local master to have all those commits.

Note also that you might get conflicts in the `git merge` if both abcd and master have edited the same sections of the same file. There's lots of help in resolving git merge conflicts.

Also: You want to make sure everything works after the merge.  It's possible that the changes on master broke an API that you were using, so you may need to make edits to deal with that.

**Update:**  My assumption about abcd being the name of the remote is wrong.

First, get the name of your remote with the `git remote` command.  Mine goes like this.

```
git remote
origin
```

So I only have one remote, and I call it origin.  That's pretty common.   If you've got more than one remote, it'll be trickier.

So, with "origin" as the remote it goes like this:

```
git checkout abcd/child
git pull
git merge origin/abcd/master
git push
```

Obviously substitute the name of your remote if it's not origin.
Same caveats apply about conflicts and making sure it works.

Comment: Thank you @GregHNZ. In the above case , abcd/child and abcd/master is both the names of the branch .Will still the above commands holds good?